# How to access this struct array in C function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I have a structure and an array of such structures:

```
typedef struct clientInformation{
    int inUse;
    int socketNumberClient;
    char *portNumber;
    int listeningPort;
    char *clientsName;
    char *clientsIP;
}clientInformation;
clientInformation client[10];
```

I initialize the array by calling this function:

```
void addToList(char *ipaddress,char *p,char *cName,int socketNumber,int clientPortListen){
int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(client[i].inUse==0){
            client[i].inUse=1;
            client[i].socketNumberClient=socketNumber;
            client[i].listeningPort=clientPortListen;
            client[i].portNumber=p;
            client[i].clientsName=cName;
            client[i].clientsIP=ipaddress;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the initialization function function from the main() function, using this:

```
addToList(clientIP,clientPort,clientName,clientSocketNew,clientPortListen);
```

The problem is that I am unable to access the members of a structure in the array after initializing. I am unsure whether the members are populated or not.

For an instance when I try to print in main() this:

> printf("%d",client[8].inUse);

It outputs nothing.

Comment: Perhaps `stdout` did not flush.  Try `printf("%d\n",client[8].inUse);`

Comment: Where and how you have declare your structure variable ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  More importantly, please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It isn't clear from what you show whether your array is a global (file scope variable, possibly with external linkage), or local to a function.  Since you don't explicitly pass it to the `addToList()` function, presumably it is global.  You shouldn't expect to see outputs until you print a newline at the end of a line — the output often won't appear until then.

Comment: The client array does not appear to be initialized, therefore it contains garbage.  Do so.  At the very least: `for(i=0;i<10;i++) client[i].inUse = 0;`

Comment: @JohnHascall I agree with you

Comment: John
I already did that.
And the output appeared. Thanks to @WarrenWeckesser
It was a flush problem.

Answer (score 1):

The comments under the question explained why the problem happened and how to solve it quite well. Sum it up here.

In order to get `stdout` flushed when you make your outputs, you need a `\n` at the end of the output.

Change

```
printf("%d",client[8].inUse);
```

To

```
printf("%d\n",client[8].inUse);
```